# NodeIntegration doesn't work [Electron/js]

Tags: javascript, electron

I got this error when I tried to enable the integration of Node in Electron:

[image]

If I remove the Node integration, it works again.

```js
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1500,
    height: 800,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
```

Comment: which mode? dev or prod?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the Content Security Policy. You can try to set style-src policy with the external styles you are using (such as Bootstrap, FontAwesome and so on).

Comment: i already do this in my html  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">

Comment: You have to add "style-src" specifying the external resources that you are using for styles.